# Python3.8: What is the merge operator(|) good for?

Tags: python, python-3.x, merge, python-3.9

In, python3.9, the merge operator (`|`), is used for merging dictionaries together. Kind of like this:

```py
foo = {1:'spam', 'eggs':2}
bar = {3:'foo', 'eggs':'foo'}
foobar = foo|bar
```

**But how is the merge operator used in python3.8 and lower, besides merging dictionaries together?**

Comment: You can look at the PEP here https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0584/#specification

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `|` operator has magic method `__or__`. It is also used to express `set` union (merging), as well as bitwise or.

Comment: Wait, so it is also the `or` operator in python? I thought only the `or` keyword was it

Comment: No, the `or` keyword is distinct from `|` (bitwise or, also used to express union).

Comment: So, what't the difference between the `bitwise or` and the `or` keyword?

Comment: @theX You can read more at https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators (note the final heading 'Other Classes').

Comment: The `or` keyword will evaluate the left hand side expression. If that result is truthy, it will return it, otherwise it will return the right hand side. For example `0b011 | 0b100 == 0b111`, while `0b011 or 0b100 == 0b011`